# How to "text scroll" on a Text-Based Adventure Game setting?

Tags: c++, text, keyboard, key

I am making a text-based PokeMon adventure game and I was wondering how to "text scroll" in the menu instead of making a:

```
cout << "MENU" << endl;
cout << "[N] New Game" << endl;
cout << "Mode: ";
cin >> option;
```

If you don't know what I mean by "text scrolling" then here is what I want:

```
#####MENU################################# Now when I press "s" or "down" that
>[N] New Game                            # ">" thing will go down to where the
+[L] Load Game                           # "+" symbol is. And when they press
#[O] Options                             # "enter" they are taken to the loading
#0.0.1a                                  # screen. This also works by pressing
########################################## the "w" or "up" keys.
```

Is there a way to do it or do I need an external library?

Comment: You need an external library.  Standard output is linear and one-directional.

Comment: Check [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library. Is the de facto library for GUI-like terminal-based interfaces

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for the help guys, I'll be sure to check out the "ncurses" library.

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks for the help guys, I'll be sure to check out the "ncurses" library.